# Find function not working when searching for a word through macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am unable to search a word which I know is there in an excel sheet, when searching using macro. I have checked all the options but could not find why is this happening. var2 is 1082591.html and 1082592.html and so on. When I am finding Total in the excel it is not finding it. Thanks

```
Sub DataPull()
Dim Website
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
var1 = 2
Do Until Range("A" & var1) = ""
var2 = Range("A" & var1).Value
Hostteam = Range("C" & var1).Value
Hosts = Hostteam & " innings"
Visitorteam = Range("D" & var1).Value
Visitors = Visitorteam & " innings"
Website = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/indian-premier-league-2017/engine/match/" & var2
Set myIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
myIE.Navigate Website
myIE.Visible = True
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
SendKeys "^a"
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
SendKeys "^c"
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=var2
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
Cells.Find(What:=Hosts, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Cells.Find(What:="Total", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Range("J" & var1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Workbooks(var2).Activate
Cells.Find(What:=Visitors, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Cells.Find(What:="Total", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Range("L" & var1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
myIE.Quit
Set myIE = Nothing
Err.Clear
Workbooks(var2).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Range("O" & var1).Value = "Done"
var1 = var1 + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: We will not be able to work out why your code isn't working unless you paste into the question the code that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Write these 2 lines before the search for "Totals" to see what is your active cell and in which sheet:

```
debug.print activecell.address
debug.print activecell.parent.name
Cells.Find(What:="Total", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Copy
```

That could be a reason for not finding it. If this is the case, consider not searching for `After:ActiveCell`, but use a variable to set it.

Comment: Thanks, the macro is searching the data for first two iterations but not after that. I tried manually searching as well but then find seems to be disabled in this excel sheet. I am unable to figure out the issue.